Unable to Install Companion App
Integrating salesforce and slack, i'm unable to install the "companion app" from the Salesforce AppExchange. It seems the URL might be invalid.  Could you please share the updated URL for the Companion App or let me know if anything has changed regarding the Slack integration?"
Refered Blog : https://www.salesforceben.com/slack-to-salesforce-integration/  .

I have this same problem, and am guessing this really needs a support case with Salesforce.
